# Start systemd-nspawn and execute commands inside

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, systemd

I didn't find a question like this. I have a bash script (running in Debian) that start a `systemd-nspawn` session. After that I would like to continue my script as I am in the spawned machine:

```
#!/bin/bash
systemd-nspawn -q --bind /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static -D /mnt/project /bin/bash

apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade
```

After executing the `systemd-nspawn` command, the script is suspended and the prompt of the console is inside the spawned system. When I exit the script resumes but in the LOCAL machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple alternatives how you can approach your problem:

1. Make a script you execute inside systemd-nspawn container and place the commands you wish to run there (`systemd-nspawn -D .. /your-script`). If you want to get interactive shell after running your commands, place something like `exec bash -i` at the end of script .
2. If you want to keep your current script, you could provide your commands as input to bash:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    systemd-nspawn --pipe -q --bind /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static -D /mnt/project /bin/bash << EOF
    apt-get update
    apt-get -y upgrade
    EOF
   ```

   This works fine if you don't require an interactive shell afterwards.

Comment: In 2019, I think you have to pass `systemd-nspawn --pipe` for this to work.